# How to place textfield in table view controller to read contents

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I am a little stuck after reading a tutorial and trying to go it alone.

Essentially I am trying to link my form components (the text boxes and buttons) to my view controller window via control click and drop. In the book this looks fairly simple as its just a case of drag and drop but when I do it, nothing happens!

Please could someone give me some indication as to why this could be?

[image]

Comment: You probably forgot to change the class of the UITableViewController in your storyboard to LoginTableViewController. Select the tableViewController in the storyboard and check the class inspector in Xcodes sidebar. Looks like you changed the class of the UITableView, but did not change the class of the UITableViewController.

Comment: thats exactly what it was - thank you - sorry for such an easy question I'm just starting out with this language / platform!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the class of the UITableViewController in your storyboard to LoginTableViewController. Select the tableViewController in the storyboard and check the class inspector in Xcodes sidebar.You can change there to LoginTableViewController.